# Adding post date to ACF field

Tags: posts, date

I'm using ACF to display a featured post on the front end of my site. I need the date of the post to be displayed as well. Here is my current code:`

---

## FEATURED POST

---

ID), full ); // this fetches the featured post's thumbnail. $thumbnail[0] <-- this is the image's URL

```
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($featured_post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($featured_post->ID); ?></a></h3>

        <p><?php echo custom_excerpt($featured_post->post_content, 2000, ''); // this function is defined in functions.php ?></p>


    </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_the_time() to get the post time .

```
<?php get_the_time( $format, $featured_post->ID ); ?>
```

See the tutorial
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time

Comment: <?php get_the_date( $format, $featured_post->ID ); ?>

Comment: but how do I change the date format ?

Comment: Ah its in the settings in my wp-admin. Thanks for your help

Comment: Go through this tutorial about date formats - [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)